# MSBuild Sonar Runner Resharper Cannot Create Canonical Path

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, resharper, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

Running `MSBuildSonarRunner 1.0.1.0`, having run `inspectcode.exe` to generate a resharper violations report.

When the sonar runner parses the report, it generates an error: **it cannot create a canonical path**.

It looks to be appending the location of the `msbuild script` to the full path to the file containing the violations.

However on other solutions we have this is working without issue.

> 15:52:38  15:52:38.510 INFO  - Parsing ReSharper report: C:{somepath}\inspectcode.xml (TaskId:25836)
>
> 15:52:38  15:52:38.758 INFO  - Skipping the ReSharper issue at line 314 which has no associated file. (TaskId:25836)
>
> 15:52:38  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ (TaskId:25836)
>
> 15:52:38  INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE (TaskId:25836)
>
> 15:52:38  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ (TaskId:25836)
>
> 15:52:38  Total time: 48.819s (TaskId:25836)
>
> 15:52:38  Final Memory: 15M/414M (TaskId:25836)
>
> 15:52:38  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ (TaskId:25836)
>
> 15:52:38  ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution (TaskId:25836)
>
> 15:52:38  ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar (TaskId:25836)
>
> 15:52:38  ERROR: Caused by: Fail to get the canonical path of C:{somepath}\C:{somepath}{somefile} (TaskId:25836)
>
> 15:52:38  ERROR: Caused by: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect (TaskId:25836)

Comment: It's not clear on what you are asking. Can you add the code you were trying to run and what error message(s) didi you receive?

Comment: It seems that you hid the most important information: The actual canonical path is it trying to get.

Comment: Could you provide: 1. the path causing the issue, as it appears in the resharper XML, 2. the absolute path to the solution file, 3. the value of the "sonar.resharper.solutionFile" property you pass during the analysis, 4. the complete failing path causing the error, as present in the logs, 5. the SonarQube server version